# pass the attribute when the button click other the attribute value sholud be null

Tags: html, angularjs

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.value=function(){
             $scope.users=[{name:abc,email:abc@gmail.com,course:angular js}]
      }
 </script>
 <body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="value()">To get values</button>
   <div ng-repeat="user in users">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
      <select ng-model="user.course">
       <option value="html">html </option>
       <option value="css">css</option>
       <option value="angular js">angular js</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

i want the the values only when the button is clicked otherwise the values of the input is default null upto to the user enters the values  in the text filed

Comment: Could you please put it little more detailed, regarding what exactly needs to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize array out side of the function and assign values to array inside of the function

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.users=[ 
     {name:'',email:'',course:''}
 ]
   $scope.value=function(){
       $scope.users=[{             
         name:'abc',
         email:'abc@gmail.com',
         course:'angular js'
       }]
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="value()">To get values</button>
   <div ng-repeat="user in users">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
     <input typee="text" ng-model="user.email">
     <select ng-model="user.course">
       <option value="html">html </option>
       <option value="css">css</option>
       <option value="angular js">angular js</option>
     </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @banu prakash check demo again